# Math expression on Regex expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have many text rows, and I must find some rows, and to change them.

I wrote such regex rule:

```
^(Position) ([0-9]+)$
```

For example, I must find all such rows:

Position 10
Position 11
Position 12

Now I must increase numbers at 5. How can I do it through Regex?
I try to wrote such regex rule:

```
$1 {$2+ 5}
```

I need get result:

Position 15
Position 16
Position 17

But I have got:

Position {10 +5}
Position {11+5}
Position {12+5}

Answer (score 5):

the Regex Replace function takes either a string, or a function. you used the string replacement, so just the string is inserted. if you want an integer operation, you need to use the replace with function method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cft8645c(v=vs.80).aspx

this code is not correct, it should just show the way how it could be done

```
 Regex.Replace("^(Position) ([0-9]+)$", ReplaceFunction);


 public string ReplaceFunction(Match m)  { return "Position " + (int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value) + 5); };
```

Comment: Not far off corerct, you just need `var result = Regex.Replace(input, ` and then your other two parameters. And you need `Groups[2]` as `Groups[0]` is the _whole match_, not the first group.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In my program I must to ask to user two rules: 1. For search. 2. For replacing. It can be different rules, not static. At other situation it can be other changing rule

Comment: ReplaceFunction it is fixed in a code, but user must to has capability for set rule for search, and rule for changing via strings manually.

Comment: then your can add a formula evaluator with another input. here is a nice example: http://www.jarloo.com/c-formula-evaluator/ not so fast, but its a very good idea

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = @"Position 10";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "^Position ([0-9]+)$", match => "Position " + Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) + 5);
```

Comment: The lambda expression is fixed in a code, but user must to has capability for set rule for search, and rule for changing via strings manually.